# Why is incomputability weaker than Kolmogorov complexity?

Tags: computability, kolmogorov-complexity

[Abbot et al.](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1402-4896/aaf36a) ["Experimentally probing the algorithmic randomness and incomputability of quantum randomness"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08762) remark that "incomputability is a weaker property than Kolmogorov randomness".  I understand that a Kolmogorov random infinite sequence is incomputable.  The statement implies that there are incomputable sequences that are not Kolmogorov random.  Why?  (It's difficult for me to imagine what such a sequence would be like. If the answer is complicated, pointers to textbooks or literature at a similar level would be welcome.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take your favorite noncomputable infinite binary sequence $f$ and consider the new sequence $$g:=f(0), 0, f(1), 0, f(2), 0, ...$$ Clearly $g$ is again noncomputable ($f$ and $g$ have the same **Turing degree**), but $g$ also has lots of "predictable behavior" since every other bit of $g$ is zero. This prevents $g$ from being Kolmogorov random. So, in fact, not only does noncomputability not imply randomness, but every noncomputable sequence has the same Turing degree as a non-random sequence.

Comment: Thanks--so simple and clear.  (I think that one is supposed to indicate thanks only with upvote and checking "answered" rather than comments, but sometimes that feels unsatisfying.)